# Update error - Error: core-issue#2487 Add / alter defaults for civicrm_contribution_recur

Tags: drupal, upgrade, drupal-7

I get an update error when updating - see attached screen capture. [image]

The error happens when upgrading from 5.36 to 5.37 and 5.38 (which is currently the latest). The error occurs when using the browser and drush to update.

Running Drupal version: 7.81 (currently the latest)

There are Civi extension updates, I normally update Civi before extensions. Not sure if this is causing an issue.

I can also upload the drush error log as well if that will help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Similar problem for me - from 5.36 to 5.37 (starting all the way from 5.22.1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is contribution_status_id - it can't set the default value because it isn't able to find the status corresponding to Pending. Did you maybe delete that status in your system?

Comment: I don' think I removed the status, doesn't mean it not there though. Do you know how can I check? And how I can add it back in?

Comment: When you go to Contributions - New Contribution, is Pending a  choice for the status field on the form?

Comment: Yes, Pending is an option

Comment: Hmm, that's confusing then. Maybe somehow the internal machine name field has been changed. If you go to Support - Developer - Api3 and choose entity OptionValue and action get and then for parameters Option Group ID = contribution status and Option Label = Pending, what is the output for the `name` field?

Comment: Here is the line: "name": "Pending",

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this error? I'm hitting it too...

Comment: Hi pyfi. I didn't find a solution. Did you find a solution?